# Словообразовательная цепочка слова "Подарочный"

Tags: словообразование

Доброго времени суток! Прошу помочь составить словообразовательную цепочку слова "подарочный".

Comment: Бывает ещё "подзаборный"! Щютка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

дарить - подарить - подарок - подарочный